# phpDocumentor alternative consuming less memory

Tags: php, doxygen, phpdoc

Okay, I'm fed up with [phpDocumentator](http://www.phpdoc.org/). It consumes way much more memory (1.4 GB) and time (5 minutes on 2.6GHz Core 2 Duo) than I'm willing to give it. Does there exist some really compatible program to generate documentation for PHP code?

I've tried [PHPDoctor](http://peej.github.com/phpdoctor/), which looks nice, but it has some [missing features](http://www.phpdoc.org/). However it is probably closest to be replacement from all solutions I've tried so far.

I've also tried [PhpDocGen](http://www.arakhne.org/phpdocgen/index.html), but it just bails out with some Perl errors, which I'm too lazy to study.

Doxygen also does not seem to play well with our sources.

PS: The documentation would be for [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/), a little bit outdated documentation is [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/phpdoc/).

Update: The code contains lot of functions and not only objects, what is the biggest problem with Doxygen, because it fails to organize them.

Comment: Out of interest, how memory intensive is it for your specific project?

Comment: It crashed with 1 GB limit and it still had lot of files to process.

Comment: mmm. I seriously don't see the problem.  it's not like you run PHPdocumentor 24 hours a day. like you said - it's 5 min deal that's part of your build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen is pretty complex, and it's supposed to support PHP 5.3 features. However, it didn't work exactly how I wanted it and I realized it's a big program, but not designed for PHP; so I needed something lighter, simpler and preferably PHP exclusive, because let's face it, PHP does not have quite the common programming language syntax and look.

I know you mentioned it, but I chose PHPDoctor in the end. It does indeed lack some features, but it's simple and fast, exactly what I was looking for.

Let us know what you chose and what were the reasons.

Also something to mention is that I found the PHPDoctor interface to be quite simple and easy to style (with few CSS changes). I was able to create quite a clean page for my docs.

Answer (score 3):

We switched from phpDocumentor to [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) because the former did not support PHP 5.3 features like namespaces and closures. phpDocumentor's last update was in 2008.

The major `@`-attributes are the same in Doxygen, because they both do JavaDoc-style comments. It is quite configurable, too.

Comment: I see several problems with Doxygen, but maybe I'm just unable to configure it properly. It does not handle file level comments and creates huge mess out of it in namespace documentation. It does not generate documentation for functions unless `EXTRACT_ALL` is enabled and it still does not provide some easy way to browse functions besides going through files. Also it does not support @uses and @subpackage.

Comment: We do not use `@subpackage` (that is what namespaces do now) or `@uses` (no use for it, hah). As for file level comments: that can indeed be a problem, but we follow the "one class per file" approach so we just use class comments.

Comment: Having just classes would make the things probably easier, but it is not the case (yet).

Answer (score 3):

You can also try DocBlox; it is a new kid on the block (pun intended) but already supports many of the features that phpDocumentor provides and many of the newer things (like namespaces).
Please try it out at https://www.github.com/mvriel/Docblox

Comment: It still focuses on object code and classes and is pretty much useless for code which contains mostly functions. Just try it on phpMyAdmin.

Comment: What kind of organization do you have in mind? Apparently you expect documentation generation tools to somehow group these functions into logical sections.
For classes and files this is done by class, namespace and the @package tag in the docblock. functions are commonly only grouped on the file level (which you might group using the @package tag)

Comment: @Mike van Riel I love Docblox. I use it with the comments I wrote for PHPDocumentor without any changes, and it is great. Any interest in developing an HTML interface?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/), works well for me

Comment: It might be good option, but it would mean converting all the documentation to new format, which is work I'd like to avoid.